# HttpWebRequest Refused When Sent from Specific Server

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a basic program which utilizes a specific API for a cloud hosting provider.  The program makes a `HttpWebRequest` which is essentially like a request to perform an action to one of the servers in the cloud (ex. shut it down, start it up).

The issue that I am having is that the script works when I execute it from my local machine but not when I execute it from one of our production servers.  The server in question is a `Windows 2008 R2` box (virtual/hosted) and is going to be the script host if I can get this script working there.

The funny thing is this script has been working in the production environment before (automated via the Windows Task Scheduler) for at least several weeks.  Then, all of the sudden, it stopped working yesterday.  There are no server changes of which I am aware, but I am not the only one with access to the environment, so changes could have been made there.  I am a little bit concerned that perhaps some security or firewall setting is what is causing the issue.  We recently installed new virus protection software, so that is a potential culprit.

1. Is this `HttpWebRequest` not proper in some way which would make it be blocked or fail somehow?
2. Is there a specific server setting I should check that could have an adverse affect on this specific program?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

class Script {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string organizationId = args[0];
        string serverId = args[1];
        string serverCommand = args[2];
        string username = args[3];
        string password = args[4];
        string credentials = username + ":" + password;
        credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(credentials));

        //send command to server
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.opsourcecloud.net/oec/0.9/" + organizationId + "/server/" + serverId + "?" + serverCommand);
        HttpWebRequest serverRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        serverRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + credentials;
        HttpWebResponse serverResponse = (HttpWebResponse)serverRequest.GetResponse();

    }

}
```

Here is my error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote se
rver ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made becaus
e the target machine actively refused it 168.143.82.65:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
ss socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Sock
et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Script.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with your `Authorization` header. Try using `NetworkCredential` instead on your request like this:

```
serverRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: I tried that and got the same behavior.  The request was successful when sent from my local machine, but when coming from the server, it threw the exception described above.  Your suggestion does look like cleaner code though, so I will probably keep that change anyway.

Comment: It's perhaps a firewall issue or the server is denying a response because you have made too many subsequent requests at a time.